# Can't get text inside strong tag

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="some_class>    
  <p>
   <strong>
     some text
   </strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

I try to use
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to strong tab").text
but this print empty string

Comment: If you catch the path correctly, you dont have any errors. Check the path you use inside xpath.

Comment: I did check the path and everything is correct. I was able to get the text from another p tag above it, but that one doesn't have a strong tag inside it

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks --- Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try printing the textContent Attribute if text is not in view port or is not displayed:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to strong tab").get_attribute("textContent")
```

ALso you could try

```
strong = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to strong tab")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",strong)
print(strong.text)
```

This will bring the element into view

Answer (score 0):

There are chances that there are multiple `<strong>` tabs in your page.

Try the following:

```
allStrongs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("xpath to strong tab")

for aStrong in allStrongs:

     print(aStrong.text)
```

Comment: There's only 1 strong tag inside the p tag